# Determining if a file is a picture or video based on extension not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I am trying to determine if a file that is uploaded is either a video or photo. I need this so that based on the file extension, I can send a video or photo to my telegram bot.

What is throwing me off, is that the logic I have seems to be right:

```
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error')
        } else {
            console.log('File uploaded : ' + files.upload.path + '/' + files.upload.name);
            console.log('Fields : ' + fields);
            console.log(path.extname(files.upload.name))
            if(path.extname(files.upload.name).toLowerCase() === ".jpeg" || ".jpg" || ".png" || ".tiff" || ".gif") {
                console.log("image")
            }
            else if(path.extname(files.upload.name).toLowerCase() === ".mp4" || ".m4a"|| ".f4v" || ".m4b" || ".mov") {
                console.log("video")
            }
            else {
                render('error')
            }
            res.render('success')
        }
    });
```

When uploading an .mp4 video file, it prints that it is a .mp4, but then prints image. I'm unsure as to why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you really don't, because we lie about file types all the time, and some applications don't even care, so someone could upload a .gif that's actually an .mp4 (which is _really_ common these days). What you really need to do is look at the actual file contents and look for [the magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) for each filetype you want to support. Each image format, and each video format, has public documentation that tells you exactly which bytes to look for, and what their values _have_ to be for a file to be a legal jpg/png/avi/mp4/etc/etc

Comment: After looking into this, this seems more practical. I have found this package, [magic-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/magic-number) that I plan on using. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your code

```
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
        res.render('error')
    } else {
        console.log('File uploaded : ' + files.upload.path + '/' + files.upload.name);
        console.log('Fields : ' + fields);
        console.log(path.extname(files.upload.name))
        let extension = path.extname(files.upload.name).toLowerCase();
        if(extension  === ".jpeg" || extension === ".jpg" || extension === ".png" || extension === ".tiff" || extension === ".gif") {
            console.log("image")
        }
        else if(extension  === ".mp4" || extension === ".m4a"|| extension === ".f4v" || extension  === ".m4b" || extension  === ".mov") {
            console.log("video")
        }
        else {
            render('error')
        }
        res.render('success')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The or comparison your are attempting to use is not working as you think it is.  Only your first comparison is using the value of `path.extname(files.upload.name).toLowerCase()`, the others are evaluting string's truthiness and returning appropriately. As such that first `if` is always going to be entered.

E.g.

```
> x = 5
5
> if ( x == 4 || ".jpg" ) {console.log("Yep")};
Yep
> if ( x == 5 && "" ) {console.log("Yep")};
undefined
> if ( x == 5 && "yep" ) {console.log("Yep")};
Yep
```